Claim based Authentication and jwt authorization
I have created User, UserOperationClaim, OperationClaim tables for using Authentication:
 public class User : IEntity
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public byte[] PasswordSalt { get; set; }
    public byte[] PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UserOperationClaim> UserOperationClaims { get; set; }
    
 }

 public class UserOperationClaim
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int OperationClaimId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public OperationClaim OperationClaims { get; set; }
}


public class OperationClaim
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UserOperationClaim> UserOperationClaims { get; set; }
}

I have created login & register controller:
    [HttpPost("login")]
    public ActionResult Login(UserForLoginDto userForLoginDto)
    {
        var userToLogin = _authService.Login(userForLoginDto);
        if(!userToLogin.IsSuccess)
        {
            return BadRequest(userToLogin.Message);
        }

        var result = _authService.CreateAccessToken(userToLogin.Data);
        if(result.IsSuccess)
        {
            return Ok(result);
        }

        return BadRequest(result.Message);
    }

    [HttpPost("register")]
    public ActionResult Register(UserForRegisterDto userForRegisterDto)
    {
        var userExists = _authService.UserExists(userForRegisterDto.Email);
        if(!userExists.IsSuccess)
        {
            return BadRequest(userExists.Message);
        }

        var registerResult = _authService.Register(userForRegisterDto);
        var result = _authService.CreateAccessToken(registerResult.Data);
        if(result.IsSuccess)
        {
            return Ok(result.Data);
        }

        return BadRequest(result.Message);
    }

but I didn't know what to do and how, can someone explain that?
When I tried login & register, its successful. But when I add product I get

unauthorized

and I can't see who has what authority to add products.

Hi, can you share the code of the product controller ? Do you have specific roles needed to access the product controller and actions ? When you create the user do you give him/her roles ?

Hi. I don't assign a role when i create the user. Because someone told me you should the roles in jwt claims when user registered but i don't understand where and how to role. In my products controller i don't put authorize attribute and it has like getAll, getById, getByCategoryId, add, delete, update methods

If you have 'unauthorized' response from product controller it means you have configured Authorization elsewhere, in the Startup maybe. You should check the code that authenticate your user and if you send to Token in the request from your client as well. For examples and information about authentication =>
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/
https://medium.com/@microclip.lakeesha/net-core-6-token-based-authentication-and-middleware-43a5fc86089a
